# Search and move files in S3 bucket according to metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, lambda, metadata

I currently have a setup where audio files are uploaded to a bucket with user defined metadata. My next goal is to filter through the metadata and move the files to a different folder. Currently I have lambda a lambda function that converts the audio to mp3. So I need help to adjust the code so that the metadata persists through the encoding and is also stored in a database. And to create another function that searches for a particular metadata value and moves the corresponding files to another bucket.

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

const elastictranscoder = new aws.ElasticTranscoder();

// return basename without extension
function basename(path) {
   return path.split('/').reverse()[0].split('.')[0];
}

// return output file name with timestamp and extension
function outputKey(name, ext) {
   return name + '-' + Date.now().toString() + '.' + ext;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
       const key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

       var params = {
         Input: { 
           Key: key
         },
         PipelineId: '1477166492757-jq7i0s', 
         Outputs: [
           {
             Key: basename(key)+'.mp3',
             PresetId: '1351620000001-300040', // mp3-128
           }
         ]
       };

       elastictranscoder.createJob(params, function(err, data) {
         if (err){
           console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
           context.fail();
           return;
         }
         context.succeed();
       });
};
```

I also have done some research and know that metadata should be able to be pulled out by

```
s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your actual question? Of your desires (move, retrieve metadata, store metadata, search metadata), on which one are you seeking help? What have you tried and what happened?

Comment: To clarify I can store metadata to the audio file, and I know how to retrieve it. The question is how do I search through the metadata on what could be 100's of audio files and move them from one bucket to another?

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not provide a mechanism for searching metadata.

The only way to do what you're contemplating using only native S3 capabilities is to iterate through the list of objects and send a `HEAD` request for each object but of course this does not scale well for large buckets and each of those requests comes with a charge, although it is a small one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there exists the S3 inventory tool that allow to extract information out of the S3 objects including metadata and the information can be retrieved for instance using [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html) queries.

Details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html).